# How to deploy jar in eclipse maven remote repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, jar

i am working with others developers on eclipse project. The project is hosted on SVN. I wonder how I can add JAR file to the dependencies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific...

What do you want to do? Add some jar files to your SVN repository?

This is strange...cause you have to share on SVN just the project not compiled, to be able to evolve the code line wit your team...but not the jar files...they could be published on a remote repository like Artifactory or Nexus but no under SVN, for me, it does not make sense.

Not on SVN...but maybe, simply, i don't understand your question...

Try see this -----> [Java jar files into a repository (CVS, SVN..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649015/java-jar-files-into-a-repository-cvs-svn)

Answer (score 0):

First, what do you mean *I wonder how I can add JAR file to the dependencies.*?

Do you mean that you need to add a jar to the compile classpath in Eclipse? Do you mean there's a jar that you need to access whether locally built or from some open source project somewhere on the web?

Is this a jar that Project "A" builds and Project "B" needs?

You can simply check the jar into Subversion. That way, when someone checks out the project, they have the jar. This is a common way to handle this issue, and it's known as *the wrong way*.

The *right way* is to use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), and then use a third party Jar repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) to host your locally built jars that your projects need. Then, use [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) or [IvyDE](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) to connect your repo to your Eclipse project.

Doing things the right way is a bit more difficult, and you and your developers will have to learn Maven or Ivy and how it works. In the end, it makes your development faster and easier. Plus, knowing something like this can help your future career.