# Where to "store" large video files which are part of website?

Tags: svn, video, repository

i have the code, images / css / js all stored as part of a svn repository, but i'm not sure what to do with several large video files that are part of my site as well...

should i:

1. upload them from my local machine whenever needed (no svn)
2. check them into main repository
3. keep them in a different repository and update from it when needed
4. keep them in a location like S3 and pull them when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely suggest that you keep a backup somewhere centrally. So option 1 is out.

If you want to use SVN, it will depend. The reason why people generally don't like to store binary files in SVN is that binary deltas are usually useless. According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538643/how-good-is-subversion-at-storing-lots-of-binary-files) SVN also isn't good at storing very large files.

However, if you only have a few video files, that fall within the limits that SVN can handle. And if they aren't going to change too much, I would go ahead and put them in SVN. This will be the easiest solution with the least hassle.

Otherwise, I would look into a solution that doesn't require too many build steps. I'd suggest to point your links to the videos directly to S3 and not have an intermediary step of pulling the videos into your application and then deploying to a sever.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this stackoverflow answer: [How good is Subversion at storing lots of binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538643/how-good-is-subversion-at-storing-lots-of-binary-files)

I personally have run into weird errors when using SVN to store files > 1Gb. I suspect it would be better to have them in a seperate (non-versioned) directory, and pull them in when needed.

Not to mention the hassle when you want to do a new checkout and have to wait hours before the full tree is in ...