# How do I track a file, but not duplicate it, using svn?

Tags: svn, large-data

I have a 10GB binary file that I'd like to include with a subversion project, that I would like others to have access to, but I've read that SVN duplicates all files to be able to track changes.

I don't want this 10GB to be duplicated, but I don't want it to be ignored either. Is there a middle ground, or do I have to ask everyone to ignore the file and bring it in outside of SVN?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How good is Subversion at storing lots of binary files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538643/how-good-is-subversion-at-storing-lots-of-binary-files)

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen that one. I was hoping to find a different feature – something more along the lines of "download, but don't track differences, for this file." Sadly, it looks like SVN doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible (at least that was the case when I last looked).

As a workaround, you could commit the file to the repository, and have people use `svn export` to get a local copy of it (instead of using checkout). Of course, this means, that people will have to manually update it (svn export again) when it changed. (`svn update` won't work).

Comment: Hold on – if I commit it, wouldn't it then be tracked on my end and duplicated? And how would I be able to check out the containing folder without checking out the 10GB file before calling svn export on it?

Comment: @Nick Sweet: You would have to either commit it outside of the folder containing your project, or alternatively do a sparse-checkout (which omits some folders).